# Arguing whether a function is one to one

Tags: functions

The function is $x^{2}-1$. How exactly would you go about arguing that it is one to one? (Or not one to one if that were to be the case). I know it isn't since I know what the function looks like.

Comment: Use the [horizontal line test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_line_test).

Comment: By simple counterexample. (Assuming) $f: R \to R$, then $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x$, so is not one to one.

Answer (score 2):

The question is : are there two distinct $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ where $f(x)=x^2-1$. If yes then $f$ isn't injective. To answer this question notice that 
$$f(a)=f(b)\iff a^2=b^2\iff (a-b)(a+b)=0\iff a\pm b$$
so take $b=-a\ne a\iff a\ne0$ and we have $f(b)=f(a)$ and this function isn't injective.

Answer (score 1):

Note that usually $1\ne -1$, but $f(-1)=0=f(1)$, voila.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the unusual case when $1=-1$?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTby_e4-Rhg

Comment: @Moron Mostly when $2=0$. In that case, $x\mapsto x^2-1$ is indeed injective.